# Disappearing tokens

Tags: tokens

Has anyone seen tokens disappear? First I noticed `[site:name]` gone, then I entered the Patterns section of URL aliases and saw a bunch of errors caused by invalid tokens. In particular, the following tokens became unrecognized:
a taxonomy term token `[term:parents:join:/]`
a node token `[node:field-kateg-zastos:url:path]`

I have an (almost) mirror copy of the site, with the same version of Token (1.1) installed, and without any token problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got solved through regression tests on a site copy, with a surprising outcome: The Node export module is at fault, even the latest development snapshot (7.x-3.0-rc3+32-dev) built on 17 Jun 2012. An issue has been [filed](http://drupal.org/node/1638146#comment-6130182) for the module.

Answer (score -1):

Ensuring that the module 'Entity Tokens' is installed and enabled is another possible solution.

Comment: The tokens the OP is referring are not defined from the Entity Tokens module.